# Converting rows into nested elements with xslt

Tags: xslt

Input:

```
<data>
  <line>1grandparent-fname</line>
  <line>2parentfname</line>
  <line>3child1name</line>
  <line>4child2name</line>
  <line>3child1name</line>
  <line>4child2name</line>
  <line>5parent-lname</line>
  <line>6grandparent-lname</line>
</data>
```

Expected output:

```
<data>
  <grandparent fname="Grandparent-fname" lname="grandparent-lname">
    <parent fname="parentfname" lname="parent-lname">
      <child1>child1name</child1>
      <child2>child2name</child2>
      <child1>child1name</child1>
      <child2>child2name</child2>
    </parent>
  </grandparent>
</data>
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish with xslt? Tried with various options but couldn't figure out.

The first letter decide the hierarchy, 1 grandparent fname, 2 parent fname, 3 child1 name and so on. Parent and children repeating and child 1 and 2 will be sequential,

Comment: Will there be only one grandparent?

Comment: Yes. One Grandparent.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible approach. It may not be an elegant one, but then neither is the input. It is assumed that there can be more than one grandparent and any number (including an odd one) of children.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/data">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="line[starts-with(., '1')]">
        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="'grandparent'"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="line">
    <xsl:param name="level"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$level='grandparent'">
            <xsl:variable name="end" select="following-sibling::line[starts-with(., '6')][1]" />
            <xsl:variable name="limit" select="count($end/preceding-sibling::line)" />
            <grandparent>
                <xsl:attribute name="fname">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 2)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="lname">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring($end, 2)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::line[count(preceding-sibling::line) &lt; $limit][starts-with(., '2')]">
                    <xsl:with-param name="level" select="'parent'"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </grandparent>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="$level='parent'">
            <xsl:variable name="end" select="following-sibling::line[starts-with(., '5')][1]" />
            <xsl:variable name="limit" select="count($end/preceding-sibling::line)" />
            <parent>
                <xsl:attribute name="fname">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 2)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="lname">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring($end, 2)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::line[count(preceding-sibling::line) &lt; $limit][starts-with(., '3') or starts-with(., '4')]">
                    <xsl:with-param name="level" select="'child'"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </parent>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="$level='child'">
            <child>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 2)"/>    
            </child>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you. Its working. What change I should make if the line tag is within a file tag <data><file><line>TXT</line></file><file><line>TXT</line></file></data>

Comment: @user2288031 Please do not post code in comments; instead, add a follow-up to your original question. In any case, the required modification is rather trivial and you should be able to work it out yourself - assuming ["a minimal understanding of the problem being solved"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).